# Migration to Spring Security 6 - How to implement multiple Authorization / security filter scenarios in a library

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

Since the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated and removed in Spring Boot 3, I'm having to update some of our applications running on Spring Boot.
In order to Monitor these, we have a Spring Boot Admin server and expose the actuator and the Prometheus scraper Endpoints on most Clients.
To ensure a consistent Configuration and avoid duplication we've had a custom library facilitating http security for the Actuator endpoints and optionally auto-configuring security for the Prometheus Endpoint. This was also to make sure, developers could focus on the security of their own Application.

Following code is from the Library.

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Order(ACTUATOR_FILTER_ORDER)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityProperties::class)
public class SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
    private val properties: SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityProperties,
    private val environment: ConfigurableEnvironment
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    internal val actuatorEndpointAccessPassword: String = Base64StringKeyGenerator(KEY_LENGTH).generateKey()

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        val encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessUser)
            .password(encoder.encode(actuatorEndpointAccessPassword))
            .roles(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)

        // Note: unencrypted pw in memory was deemed acceptable here
        environment.propertySources.addLast(
            MapPropertySource(
                "spring-boot-admin-metadata",
                mapOf(
                    "spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.name" to properties.actuatorEndpointAccessUser,
                    "spring.boot.admin.client.instance.metadata.user.password" to actuatorEndpointAccessPassword
                )
            )
        )
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint::class.java)).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)
    }

    public companion object {
        private const val KEY_LENGTH = 64
        public const val ACTUATOR_FILTER_ORDER: Int = SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10
        public const val DEFAULT_ACTUATOR_ACCESS_ROLE: String = "ACTUATOR_ENDPOINT_ADMIN"
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("custom.spring.utilities.security.actuator")
public data class SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityProperties(
    @NotBlank
    val actuatorEndpointAccessUser: String = "actuator-endpoint-user",
    @NotBlank
    val actuatorEndpointAccessRole: String = DEFAULT_ACTUATOR_ACCESS_ROLE
)
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Order(PROMETHEUS_FILTER_ORDER)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties::class)
public class PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
    private val properties: PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessUser)
            .password(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessPassword)
            .roles(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)
    }

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http
            .requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.to((PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class.java)))
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class.java))
            .hasAnyRole(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)
    }

    public companion object {
        public const val PROMETHEUS_FILTER_ORDER: Int = ACTUATOR_FILTER_ORDER - 1
        public const val DEFAULT_PROMETHEUS_ACCESS_ROLE: String = "PROMETHEUS_ACTUATOR_ENDPOINT_SCRAPER"
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Validated
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("custom.spring.utilities.security.prometheus")
public data class PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties(
    @NotBlank
    val actuatorEndpointAccessUser: String,
    @NotEmpty
    val actuatorEndpointAccessPassword: String,
    @NotBlank
    val actuatorEndpointAccessRole: String = DEFAULT_PROMETHEUS_ACCESS_ROLE
)
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "custom.spring.utilities.security.prometheus", name = ["actuatorEndpointAccessUser"])
@ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint(endpoint = PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class)
@ConditionalOnBean(SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter::class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(SecurityAutoConfiguration::class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties::class)
@Import(
    PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter::class
)
public class PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Following this, an application could implement it own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in much the same way and Spring did its Magic.

This setup worked fine for the most part, and I wasn't made aware of any major flaws with this.

---

**Personal attempts**

So far I've tried to initially follow the migration guide. That however turned out to be inadequate for this setup.

Exposing a `UserDetailsService` Bean won't work, as only one such Bean may be exposed. This would prevent independent configuration.

After too many attempts I have come up with this:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Order(ACTUATOR_FILTER_ORDER)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityProperties::class)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
    private val properties: SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityProperties,
    private val environment: ConfigurableEnvironment
) {
    internal val actuatorEndpointAccessPassword: String = Base64StringKeyGenerator(KEY_LENGTH).generateKey()

    @Bean(ACTUATOR_AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public fun actuatorAuthenticationManager(): AuthenticationManager {
        val encoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()

        val user = User
            .withUsername(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessUser)
            .password(encoder.encode(actuatorEndpointAccessPassword))
            .roles(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)
            .build()

        val authenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user))
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder)

        // add pw to properties

        return ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)
    }

    @Bean("actuatorFilterChain")
    @Order(1)
    public fun actuatorFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
        @Qualifier(ACTUATOR_AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME) authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint())
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint::class.java)).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)

        return http.build()
    }

    public companion object {
        private const val KEY_LENGTH = 64
        public const val ACTUATOR_FILTER_ORDER: Int = SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 10
        public const val DEFAULT_ACTUATOR_ACCESS_ROLE: String = "ACTUATOR_ENDPOINT_ADMIN"
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Order(PROMETHEUS_FILTER_ORDER)
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties::class)
public class PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter(
    private val properties: PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties
) {
    @Bean(PROMETHEUS_AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public fun prometheusActuatorAuthenticationManager(): AuthenticationManager {
        val user = User
            .withUsername(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessUser)
            .password(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessPassword)
            .roles(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)
            .build()

        val authenticationProvider = DaoAuthenticationProvider()
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user))

        return ProviderManager(authenticationProvider)
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(0)
    public fun prometheusActuatorFilterChain(
        http: HttpSecurity,
        @Qualifier(PROMETHEUS_AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME) authenticationManager: AuthenticationManager,
    ): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .securityMatcher(EndpointRequest.to((PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class.java)))
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class.java))
            .hasAnyRole(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)

        return http.build()
    }

    public companion object {
        public const val PROMETHEUS_FILTER_ORDER: Int = ACTUATOR_FILTER_ORDER - 1
        public const val DEFAULT_PROMETHEUS_ACCESS_ROLE: String = "PROMETHEUS_ACTUATOR_ENDPOINT_SCRAPER"
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "custom.spring.utilities.security.prometheus", name = ["actuatorEndpointAccessUser"])
@ConditionalOnAvailableEndpoint(endpoint = PrometheusScrapeEndpoint::class)
@ConditionalOnBean(SpringBootAdminActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter::class)
@AutoConfigureAfter(SecurityAutoConfiguration::class)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties(PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityProperties::class)
@Import(
    PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter::class
)
public class PrometheusActuatorWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

This setup requires another `authenticationManager` Bean annotated with `@Primary`.
It also leads to the `securityFilterChain` instances from the library to be ignored.
Additionally, only the authenticationManager Bean marked as Primary was properly configured. I previously tried to configure is using `HttpSecurity` like this:

```kotlin
@Bean(PROMETHEUS_AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public fun prometheusActuatorAuthenticationManager(http: HttpSecurity): AuthenticationManager {
        val auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder::class.java)
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessUser)
            .password(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessPassword)
            .roles(properties.actuatorEndpointAccessRole)
        return auth.build()
    }
```

This worked in registering the users, but resulted in a Stackoverflow due to repeated calls to the `DaoAuthenticationProvider` (or similar) when a provided User cannot be found.
I have read, that this should be done using a custom DSL in this [Spring Blog Post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter).
The lack of a comprehensive example and seeming lack of this being explored anywhere else has made it difficult for me to grasp this approach.

**My main questions therefore are:**

- Can I configure Authentication in a similar fashion?
- Is it possible to configure `HttpSecurity` using Beans, or similar to the pre-update method?
- Or is this approach flawed from the start?

The closest example I have seen so far is this: [spring-webflux-multiple-auth-mechanisms](https://github.com/jimonthebarn/spring-webflux-multiple-auth-mechanisms/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/localhost/playground/multi/auth/SecurityConfig.kt)
It is however for webflux and kept simple.

Any further reading especially examples in this direction would be greatly appreciated.
Excluding the Spring documentation, I must have read the relevant sections a dozen times. (Unless I missed something).

Thanks in advance.